# Azure WebJobs dependency injection, with non-static methods?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I am new to web-jobs so I need some help to make this clear.
I have web job.

```
public static class Functions
    {
//.....
    public static async Task RevalidateImport(
        [QueueTrigger(QueueName.StorageRevalidate)] RevalidateImportCommand command,
        TextWriter logWriter)
    {
        await logWriter.WriteLineAsync("Start");
        try
        {
            //Do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }
        await logWriter.WriteLineAsync("End");
    }
//.....
}
```

Is it possible to have non-static class, with non static web jobs? I want have unit testable class.Also I want inject some stuff in this class.

Comment: Look at this question: [Dependency injection using Azure WebJobs SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328775/dependency-injection-using-azure-webjobs-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I looks simple.
 [Azure WebJobs dependency injection with SimpleInjector.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328775/dependency-injection-using-azure-webjobs-sdk)