# Autofac and Azure WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, autofac, azure-webjobs

Our Application makes heavy use of Autofac Per-Request-Dependencies.
This works quite well and fits our needs.

Now we have an requirement to listen on AzureWebJobs.

Since im quite new to Azure WebJobs i followed [this](https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/05/10/azure-webjobs-and-dependency-injection/) tutorial (Here the [git-sources](https://github.com/ry8806/Azure-WebJobs-DI))

**Now the tricky part.**
 Even though i followed all the instructions and created an `AutofacActivator` Autofac seems not to be able to resolve my Per-Request registered dependencies

> DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a Tag matching
>   'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
>   was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered
>   as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance()
>   component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always
>   request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or
>   ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container
>   itself.

## Question

Is there any way i can under above requirements make Autofac work together with Azure-WebJobs?

To be clear, my Autofaclistener resolves just one service. That cannot be registered as SingleInstance since it gets resolved on other services too. Also i can not change my Per-Request-Stuff to `InstancePerLifetimeScope` as suggested [here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#id8)

I hope my issue and my question are self-explaining. If not , please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Azure webjobs are not web applications, they are more like console applications. They don't have a request/response semantic. They don't have http session contexts, nor request scopes. So you should not use per-request registrations, they are meaningless inside a webjob. If you insist on using per-request dependencies you will have to simulate a request context for your webjob, and this is a risky approach. You can easily introduce memory leaks and undesired side effects. Be aware that you are forcing an unnatural way to deal with dependency scopes in webjobs. See [this page about implementing custom per-request scopes](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#implementing-custom-per-request-semantics) for more info.

A simple way to deal with this is to get a dependency scope only for the lifetime of your event handler methods. You explicitly define your scope inside a `using` block (as the scopes will not be automatically created in a webjob in the way that they are automatically created in a MVC or ASP.NET application). You have to register your types as `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()`. The instances will be disposed when you exit the `using` block.

So in your event handlers you define a lifetime scope for each execution of the handler method:

```
private void OnEvent(...)
{
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        ...
        var myService = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();
        ...
    }
}
```

This example uses explicit `Resolve` calls to get the instances of your service. There are better ways to do it, like using autofac factory methods.

A more advanced solution would be to implement your own `IJobActivator`. This way you can use constructor injection in your `Functions` class, and the lifetime scope of those instances will be the lifetime of your handler method execution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727799/1182515) contains code examples. You still will need to register your types as `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your answer aint helping me. As i already mentioned, i CANNOT change the `InstancePerRequest`. As it seems what im trying to do is either impossible or really tricky

Comment: Looks like you will have to use custom per-request scopes. I hope the link above helps you. It's tricky but not impossible. Good luck!