# Using Unity to inject dependency from another project with Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unity-container, azure-webjobs

I have two projects in my solution - a web project, and a console app.

**Web Project**

From within my web project, I have the following working:

```
public class TestService : BaseService {
    private BrowseService _browseService;
    public TestService(BrowseService browseService) {
        _browseService = browseService;
    }

    public ApiResponseDto DoStuff(string username) {

        using (var db = new AppContext()) {
            var user = db.FindUser(username);
            // do stuff with _browseService here
        }
    }
 }
```

I'm using Unity for DI here.

**Console App**

Now, I reference my web project from my console app and do the following:

```
public class Functions {
    private TestService _testService;
    public Functions(TestService testService) {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    public static void ProcessStuff([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] string userId) {
        using (var db = new AppContext()) { // works
            _testService.DoStuff(userId) // _testService isn't available
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

How do I get DI working in my console app?  I've added Unity and then I do this:

```
    static void Main() {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        var host = new JobHost();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

However, the constructor above never gets hit and `_testService` is never available.

**Update**

I've attempted the following:

```
static void Main() {
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    var host = container.Resolve<JobHost>().
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

However I get an exception:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException was unhandled
>   _HResult=-2146233088   _message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost", name = "(none)". Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply this value.
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost,(none)   Resolving
>   parameter "configuration" of constructor
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost(Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration
>   configuration)
>       Resolving Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration,(none)
>       Resolving parameter "dashboardAndStorageConnectionString" of constructor Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration(System.String
>   dashboardAndStorageConnectionString)
>         Resolving System.String,(none)
>
> HResult=-2146233088   IsTransient=false   Message=Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply this value.

**Update 2**

I now have the following per this question [Dependency injection using Azure WebJobs SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328775/dependency-injection-using-azure-webjobs-sdk):

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration {
            JobActivator = new MyActivator(container)
        };
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public class MyActivator : IJobActivator {
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public MyActivator(IUnityContainer container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public T CreateInstance<T>() {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

However, `_testService` is still null and the injection constructor for `Functions` is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I have tested it on my side and worked it out. Please try to follow the code below to check whether it could help you:

**Web Project**

```
public class TestService : BaseService
{
    private BrowseService _browseService;
    public TestService(BrowseService browseService)
    {
        _browseService = browseService;
    }

    public string DoStuff(string username)
    {
        return _browseService.DoStuff(username);
    }
}

public class BaseService { }

public abstract class BrowseService
{
    public abstract string DoStuff(string username);
}

public class MyBrowseService : BrowseService
{
    public override string DoStuff(string username)
    {
        return string.Format("MyBrowseService.DoStuff is invoked with value={0}", username);
    }
}
```

**Console App**

1)Functions.cs

```
public class Functions
{
    private static TestService _testService;
    public Functions(TestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    public void ProcessStuff([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessStuff is invoked with value={0}", userId);
            string result = _testService.DoStuff(userId);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessStuff return the result:\r\n{0}", result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessStuff executed with errors.\r\n{0}\r\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You should set the WebJob function as an instance function not a static function.

2)Program.cs

```html
static void Main()
{
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<BrowseService, MyBrowseService>();
    container.RegisterType<Functions>(); //Need to register WebJob class
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration()
    {
        JobActivator = new UnityJobActivator(container)
    };
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Wow.  You rock!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DependencyResolver is an MVC construct; it isn't used in a console app. To make this work, change your main method to:

```
static void Main() {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        var host = container.Resolve<JobHost>().
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Then, as long as you use constructor injection, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Nice!  I tried this and I get `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.` - I can add the full exception to the question if you'd like.

Comment: That means you don't have enough information in your unity configuration to create a JobHost. I'd add an InjectionFactory into unity to provide the configuration parameter.

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried to follow exactly what I have in my web project, which is very minimal configuration.  All I have there is essentially `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));`.  I'd totally be willing to pay you if you're available :)

Comment: I see this and am playing with it (but the offer for a paid code review still stands, pulling my hair out here)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328775/dependency-injection-using-azure-webjobs-sdk